# IE doesn't make GET request to .cgi from second time onward if it has been cached

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cgi

I am sending one HTTP GET request to one .cgi which in turn return me the response data. It makes the GET request for the first time but second time onward it is not making GET request to .cgi. This is causing problem as I'll not get the updated data which I am reading using this .cgi call.

I know one option by which IE will make call every time by selecting the below option in IE.

```
Tools > Internet Options > under Browsing History section hit the Settings button > select Every time I visit the webpage
```

Is there any way in JavaScript/HTML other than above by which I can force IE to make .cgi call every time?

Comment: Use a cache buster, http cache headers, a post request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its a get you want you can simply modify the URL by doing something like:

```
url += "?bust=" + (new Date()).valueOf().toString(36);
```

That should work unless you're calling the URL more than once a millisecond. Of course if you already have a query string on the URL change `?bust` to `&bust`. but you guessed that